# Bash script error. Syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to work through a script to email me a notification if the load is too high on our server. I found a good one but it's giving me and error when I run it, and I can't see why.

Running the code below gives the error:

> line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

I thought I had to laid out correctly though. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

THR=10
MAIL="address@domain.com"

VAR=`uptime|awk -F, '{print $4}'|awk '{print $3}'`
OUT=`echo "$VAR $THR" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print "yes"; else print "no"}'`
if [ "$VAR" == "" ]
then
  # it's within the first 24 hours of uptime
  VAR=`uptime|awk -F, '{print $3}'|awk '{print $3}'`
  OUT=`echo "$VAR $THR" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print "yes"; else print "no"}'`
fi
if [ "$OUT" == "yes" ]
then
  echo "The current load $VAR is greater than the threshold $THR" | mail $MAIL
  -s "Server Load Alert"
  echo "Alert generated because $VAR is greater than $THR"
else
  echo "No alert as $VAR > $THR"
fi
echo "load = $VAR"
```

Comment: execute with the flag -vx in your shebang line and check exactly what the error is!   `#!/bin/bash -vx`

Comment: Hmm the whitespace was giving me an error so I've removed that. Now I'm getting an unexpected end of file

Comment: Trying running it in debug mode, #/bin/bash --debug --verbose file.sh

Comment: Same error, is this supposed to put the contents of the error into a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no offence, but your bash style is terrible!

Here's a better version:

```
#!/bin/bash

thr=10
mail="address@domain.com"

read var _ < /proc/loadavg

if (( $(bc -l <<< "$var>$thr") )); then
    echo "The current load $var is greater than the threshold $thr" | mail "$mail" -s "Server Load Alert"
    echo "Alert generated because $var is greater than $thr"
else
    echo "No alert as $var <= $thr"
fi
echo "load = $var"
```

The changes are the following:

- Use lower case variable names, as upper case variable names are considered bad bash practice.
- Don't parse the output of the command `uptime` using millions of pipes, subshells and `awk`s because it's inefficient, the same information is obtained directly from the file `/proc/loadavg`, with a `read` builtin.
- Don't use `awk` to test for inequalities, use `bc`, it's more efficient (and you don't need a variable `$OUT` at all).
- No backticks! Use the `$(...)` construct instead (easier to read, to nest, and better bash practice).

I haven't tested the script, just corrected yours as I read it. Please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: I got the following output when running. `root@server[~]# bash /scripts/load_check.sh
: command not foundcheck.sh: line 2:
: command not foundcheck.sh: line 5:
: No such file or directory: line 6: /proc/loadavg
: command not foundcheck.sh: line 7:
/scripts/load_check.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @AdamG What are the scripts `load_check.sh` and `foundcheck.sh`? Could you edit your OP and include them there?

Comment: load_check.sh is this script that I'm excuting. I have no idea what foundcheck.sh is. I've got plenty of other scripts running on the server, I'm not sure why this one is causing such a headache.

Comment: @AdamG Ah it's about the script `check.sh`, not `foundcheck.sh`... Could you please check that the file `/proc/loadavg` exists by issuing `cat /proc/loadavg`. Could you also check that you have bash installed and check its version by issuing `bash --version`.

Comment: There is definitely no script called check.sh and I'm not running a command for that. `cat /proc/loadavg` gives me `0.32 0.29 0.27 1/235 14795` which looks correct? Lastly it's Bash 3.2.25(1)-release.

Comment: @AdamG then it should work! everything looks fine! I've just tried the script given in this post, and it works very well... are you executing exactly this script?

Comment: You're going to hate me for this. I played around with a few things, followed up a different error and I managed to get it to work by running dos2unix on it. Working perfectly now. Thanks so much for sticking with me!

Comment: @AdamG Oh no, I'm not hating you at all! Things like these happen, and my only wish is that you've learnt something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

THR=10
MAIL="address@domain.com"

VAR=`uptime|awk -F, '{print $4}'|awk '{print $3}'`
OUT=`echo "$VAR $THR" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print "yes"; else print "no"}'`
if [ "$VAR" == "" ]
then
# it's within the first 24 hours of uptime
VAR=`uptime|awk -F, '{print $3}'|awk '{print $3}'`
OUT=`echo "$VAR $THR" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print "yes"; else print "no"}'`
fi
if [ "$OUT" == "yes" ]
then
echo "The current load $VAR is greater than the threshold $THR" | mail $MAIL -s "Server Load Alert"
echo "Alert generated because $VAR is greater than $THR"
else
echo "No alert as $VAR > $THR"
fi
echo "load = $VAR"
```

This works for me. I changed so that "mail $MAIL" and -s "Server Load Alert" keeps on the same row.

Comment: I'm still getting an Unexpected end of file. Are there any changes I need to make on the server for it to be more forgiving?

Comment: Execute the script but swap #!/bin/bash with #!/bin/bash -x and post the output

Comment: I got the following output when running. `root@server[~]# bash /scripts/load_check.sh : command not foundcheck.sh: line 2: : command not foundcheck.sh: line 5: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file`